# Install an apk from server without downloading

Tags: android, webserver, apk

Wanted to install an apk from my server without downloading, in android.
Found the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://192.168.00.0:0000/mobile_base/test.apk"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Could somebody please explain to me where is the directory **mobile_base** located in the server, according to the Url there above. Or maybe if you have a better way of how I can get to the files via IP as the Url. Am new to android.

Comment: In the document root of the server. Well if it is indeed a directory.

Comment: You did not tell if your intent works. What happens?

Comment: After running adding the folder in the Documents directory, and running the activity, it returns error:

Comment: Webpage at http: 192.....:1433/mobile_base/app.apk  could not be loaded beause: 
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: It made no sense adding that folder to Documents directory.  Or anyhow its irrelevant.  Running the activity? Which browser is started? How?

Comment: You use a local ip address so the apk is on some pc in your lan. I wonder that you would not know path of directory.

Comment: Ok, first, am using windows machine as my server so I put the folder in C:\Windows which is my root directory. About the activity, I meant the intent.